# How to Insert an incremental variable with Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, auto-increment

This, I'm sure is a pretty basic question about JavaScript, so apologies in advance.

I have simple unordered list:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="">Item number 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Item number 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Item number 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Item number 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Item number 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

How would I be able to prepend an incremental number to those 5 items,
so I get:

```
<ul>
   <li><span>1</span><a href="">Item number 1</a></li>
   <li><span>2</span><a href="">Item number 2</a></li>
   <li><span>3</span><a href="">Item number 3</a></li>
   <li><span>4</span><a href="">Item number 4</a></li>
   <li><span>5</span><a href="">Item number 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

The logic behind the increment variable is getting me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the elements using [$.each](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each.), using the index argument on the callback function, then build the `span` element using the current element, and we prepend it to the `li`:

```
$('ul li').each(function (i) {
  $('<span>'+ (i+1) +'</span>').prependTo(this);
  // or $('<span></span>').html(i+1).prependTo(this);
});
```

Check the above snippet [here](http://jsbin.com/ipoba).

Note that I'm adding one to the index `i+1`, that's because the indexes are zero-based, also I wrap the addition between parentheses because it is in the middle of a string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

In steps it'd look like this:

1. You take all LI items and iterate through all of them by adding span with (lis[index]+1)
2. Next time you insert a LI element you insert it with span who's text is lis.length+1.